# Sequence composition

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $x$ be a known sequence.

If $ψ_1(n)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{n}x_k$, and $ψ_2(n)=x_n-x_{n-1}$, how can I prove that $ψ_2(ψ_1(n))=ψ_1(ψ_2(n))=x_n$?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot always do this.

Try $x_n=1$ for all integer $n$ to see two of the issues.

- $\psi_1(n)=\displaystyle \sum_{k=-\infty}^{n} 1 = \infty$, so $\psi_2(\psi_1(n))=\infty-\infty$ which is not defined.
- $\psi_2(n)=1-1=0$, so $\psi_1(\psi_2(n))=\displaystyle \sum_{k=-\infty}^{n} 0 = 0 \not = x_n$.

To get the result that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=-\infty}^{n} x_k -\displaystyle \sum_{k=-\infty}^{n-1} x_k = x_n$ you need the sums to be finite.

To get the result that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=-\infty}^{n} (x_k - x_{k-1}) = x_n$ you need $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to -\infty} x_n =0$.  Otherwise you face something similar to a constant of integration.

Comment: Well,that's true!The excercise takes for granted though that everything is finited.I should have mentioned it.It's my fault